# How to use golang echo web framework with swagger-go?

Tags: web-services, go, swagger, web-frameworks, swagger-codegen

i have setup a web server from existing `swagger.yml` using [go-swagger](https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger)
which already gives me validations and routing for the apis

I want to use [echo](https://echo.labstack.com/) web framework to develop this server futher, Is there a way to integrate these two so that i can use functionalities provided by both of them.

Basically if i implement everything in echo from scratch i give up on validations and routing provided by go-swagger out of the box and will have to write not so dev friendly annotations on echo code(compared to swagger.yml)

or any similar tool for echo ?

Comment: What did you end up doing with this problem @ashish? I'm in the same boat.

Answer (score 2):

Found this package: https://github.com/swaggo/echo-swagger
Maybe it'll help. I'm going to use it though haven't tried yet.